# 出かけることにしました - What is the meaning of this?

Tags: grammar

So I'm reading this sentence:

> 私は押し入れの奥から、夏の洋服を出して、かばんにいっぱい入れて出かけることにしました。

Basically I understand this sentence as:

> Out of the clothes in the closet, I took the Western-style summer clothes out, I put them in the bag (full), then I took them out.

If it's incorrect, please correct me. However, I don't understand why the take out part is so complicated:

> 出かけることにしました

出かける (the action of taking out) instead of 出る. Then turn it into noun with こと then しました.

Comment: Related (regarding ことにしました): https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/66127/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/13222/9831 / (regarding でかける)　https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/33239/9831 ... See also:  https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E5%87%BA%E6%8E%9B%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B/#je-51207

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 「私{わたし}は押{お}し入{い}れの奥{おく}から、夏{なつ}の洋服{ようふく}を出{だ}して、かばんにいっぱい入{い}れて**出{で}かけることにしました**。」

Your translation of that is:

> "Out of the clothes in the closet, I took the Western-style summer clothes out, I put them in the bag (full), then I took them out."

Your TL obviously makes little sense.  Why would one put clothes in a bag and (immediately) take them out?

「出{で}かける」 means "to go out", "to leave home", etc.

「出{だ}す」 means "to take something out", which you translated correctly.

Thus, it looks like someone is taking a trip, doesn't it?

Moving on to 「ことにする」.

This expression has been discussed many times before so I will be brief.

> 「Verb + ことにする」

means:

> "to decide to [Verb]"

You will encounter this expression over and over again as long as you study Japanese.

My own TL:

> "I decided to take my summer clothes out of the closet, stuff my bag with them and leave home."

(「洋服」 surely means "Western-style clothes" literally, but because what 99% of Japanese people wear on a daily basis are such clothes, the word just means "clothes" to us.)

Answer (score 2):

dekakeru means to go out, as in for a stroll or to do errands. So the speaker put the clothes in a bag and left the house.